# Отправка данных в "Оригинальные тексты Яндекс.Вебмастер"

Tags: php

Натолкните на мысль, как из собственной формы сделать отправку данных в "Оригинальные тексты Яндекс.Вебмастер"?
Авторизацию на сервисах яндекса написал, все хорошо, всё работает. Не понимаю как из своей формы передать данные в форму "Оригинальные тексты Яндекс.Вебмастер", ни когда не писал подобного рода скрипты. Ценна будет любая информация.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я, честно сказать, не знаю что такое "Оригинальные тексты Яндекс.Вебмастер" но надеюсь натолкнуть Вас на мысль у меня получится.

Что Вам нужно:

1. Зайти на "Оригинальные тексты Яндекс.Вебмастер"
2. найти форму о, которой Вы говорите
3. вписать туда что угодно
4. открыть Firebug или Chrome Tools(так вроде называется(инструменты разработчика))
5. перейти во вкладку "сеть"/"network"
6. нажать на кнопку "отравить"(или как там она называется) на форме "Оригинальные тексты Яндекс.Вебмастер".
7. посмотреть куда эти данные отправляются
8. посмотреть какие именно данные отправляются.
9. отправить свои данные со своего скрипта на скрипт яндекса с помощью curl

Например Вы увидите что-то вроде:

```
name=user1
password=pass
sex=1
```

Вам нужно будет отправить те же параметры(т.е name,password,sex) на скрипт яндекса но только со своими значениями.

Очень частая ошибка тех кто подобного никогда не делал - это не правильно представление. 
Обычно хотят как-то заполнить инпуты на странице и нажать на кнопку. Но этого сделать нельзя :)

Comment: Спасибо! Я примерно так и думал, но не имел уверенности. Есть куда развиваться, это более чем достаточно